# InetAddress.getAllByName for domain vs chrome on Android

Tags: android, dns

I have a host alias like `myservice` that is resolved as `myservice.mydomain.tld`.

I would like to do the ipaddress resolution myself; I tried to call `InetAddress.getAllByName("myservice")` in my android app but that throws `UnknownHostException`. Generell resolution works, calling `InetAddress.getAllByName("myservice.mydomain.tld")` returns expected result.

Now, when i use chrome on the same device and browse `https://myservice`, chrome is able to resolve as navigation to the page behind `https://myservice` works.

I tried to search the required calls from chromium/chrome [sources](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/) but i only found calls to `getAllByName` as [android_getaddrinfofornetwork](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/networking#android_getaddrinfofornetwork) which is the same as documented.

Any other hints on how apps like chrome do DNS resolution on android?

Comment: Browsers use more and more DNS over HTTPS for DNS needs.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I figured that they do more, the question is: what. It seems to be possible to get the IP somehow.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using [Network.getAllByName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network#getAllByName(java.lang.String))? Looks like that'll do the hostname resolution for you, and then return matching InetAddresses

Comment: Hi, yes, that is the function i am referencing to.